# How to revert a bad fixup in GIT?

Tags: git

I am sure there's a bunch of GIT users out there who's had this problem:

1. Create a branch from master. Let's call it *featureX*.
2. Somewhere, while working on *featureX*, you realize you want to make a fixup of a previous commit:

   - You commit your fix.
   - You do your rebase and squash/fixup.
3. Later you would like to rebase against your master to incorporate the latest changes into *featureX*.
4. Things break because your branches have diverged (the fixup was not done in master). You have a bad day.

This is the second time this has happened to me. The first time, I didn't have very much history in *featureX* and simply made a new branch off of master. **What's your take on this? How would you solve this?** Is it possible to `git reset` a certain reflog? In that case I could undo the rebase and move the fix commit back on top of *featureX* (using interactive rebase).

I'm sure there are different ways to go about it, but I guess this is a common problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can reset any branch to anything that was checked out before (the reflog). Because your fixup is still in FeatureX, the rebase will behave no different than if you don't do the fixup - it only matters if the divergence of master has conflicts with any of the commits in the featureX branch - fixups or not.

Secondly, when people first learn git, the fall in love with the awesomeness of rebasing. But I've gone back to merging. It's simpler, it marks history as it happened and it forces some discipline. Here is my workflow: http://dymitruk.com/blog/2012/02/05/branch-per-feature/

Comment: Thanks for answer! But since I have other changes (in reflog) made after the faulty rebase I am not interested in simply going back to before the rebase. I'd rather simply have that particular rebase undone. In other words, can I rebase the reflog? :) I currently don't have the code base at hand, but can try in 10 hours or so. About rebasing in general; I merge features back into integration branch. I rebase when I want to sync latest integration branch changes into feature branch. That's not what you do?

Comment: You'll have to understand what a rebase does. It generates patches for all commits you want to move to another starting point. It then applies them one by one. To "undo" a rebase, you simply rebase again but specify where you want to have that range of commits start from. the syntax is this: `git rebase --onto new-start beginning-of-range end-of-range`. And no, I rarely rebase. If you read my post carefully, you see that I start each piece of work or feature from the same point. From there, any manipulation is merging of features to 2 special branches that can be reset sometimes.

Comment: Also, google "git for computer scientists". You'll need to thoroughly understand how history is stored in git.